# After JUpdate my content position is gone from list - joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I used JUpdate to update a joomla 1.5.23 site to 2.5

when i tried to re-link the content area to the article i cant find the position from my main content area in the menu anymore.

the left sidebar is still there and also the right one.

Can anyone shine some light on this? i already tried all the positions from the template twice but i cant seem to find it?

--- template details ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.6//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site" >
    <name></name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <creationDate>07/2009</creationDate>
    <author>SiteGround</author>
    <authorEmail></authorEmail>
    <authorUrl></authorUrl>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <license>GNU/GPL</license>
    <description>TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
        <filename>templates.php</filename>
        <filename>template_preview.png</filename>
        <filename>error.php</filename>

        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>

    </files>
    <positions>
        <position>user4</position>            
        <position>user3</position>            
        <position>breadcrumb</position>            
        <position>user2</position>            
        <position>left</position>                  
        <position>right</position>            
        <position>debug</position>       
    </positions>
    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.tpl_siteground-j15-80.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <administration>
        <languages folder="admin">
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.tpl_siteground-j15-80.ini</language>
        </languages>
    </administration>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm not too sure why you used JUpdate to update to 2.5. I personally don't always trust 3rd party extensions to update the CMS as it sometimes causes problems. What you should do is (providing you have a backup of your old 1.6 site):</strike>

1. Upgrade to [1.6.6](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/15378/66849/Joomla_1.6.0_to_1.6.6-Stable-Patch_Package.zip) by downloading the patch and extracting it via FTP on to the root of your site
2. IN the Joomla Backend, go to **Extensions** >> **Extension Manager** >> **Find Updates**
3. If you can't find any updates, then go to **Options** and select the Long Term Release. Once saved, Purge Cache and try to find updates again.

**Update:**

change this:

```
<?php if($this->params->get('showComponent')) : ?> 
    <jdoc:include type="component" /> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

to this:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

So basically remove the PHP that is wrapped around

Comment: oh sorry i made a mistake, my old site was 1.5.23 is your method still possible if its under 1.6 ?

Comment: ahh 1.5, now that's a different case then. My answer doesn't apply to 1.5 unfortunately. I think the problem is due to the fact that the template being used for your Joomla 1.5 site is not supported for Joomla 2.5. It might be an idea for you to check the developer site for a Joomla 2.5 compatible version of the template

Comment: Uhmm ya so thats the problem... its an custom made from someone else for my customer, but im hired to update it as im cheaper haha

Comment: The area where you articles/components are displayed should come from the following bit of code in your template index.php file: `<jdoc:include type="component" />`, so ensure you have this placed somewhere in that file

Comment: i think i got this <?php if($this->countModules('right') and JRequest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>   
     <div id="maincolumn">
     <?php else: ?>
     <div id="maincolumn_full">
     <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="nopad">    
       <jdoc:include type="message" />
       <?php if($this->params->get('showComponent')) : ?>
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
       <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
     </div>

Comment: Right, so basically it's currently checking to see if the parameter to show the component has been selected. Due to parameter changes in Joomla 2.5, it's not being detected. If you provide your template.xml file in your initial question, I can convert it for you to use newer coding standards

Comment: oke the file is added, i think i converted most of it but maybe i missed something

Comment: @user3371474 - where there any `<param>` tags in the old XML file? cause currently `<?php if($this->params->get('showComponent')) : ?>` means that the parameter needs to be set to "On", to display the content area, however seeing as there are no parameters, it's not being displayed. If there were no `<param>` tags in the old XML, let me know and I will update my answer. Or if there were, please add them to your current code to I can show you how to convert them

Comment: oh sorry was reading the comments under your comment, ill try and come back to +1 you if it works :)

Comment: If you provide a zip of your template, I can take a look if you want

Comment: tell me if you downloaded it then ill take the link down haha

Comment: Ok I've got it downloaded now

Comment: I'm about to send you a link to download the fixed site and an email with instructions/login details. Shall I send it to the email address that was assigned to your profile on the website?

Comment: uhmm it would be awesome if you could send it too jurjenfolkertsma@hotmail.com

Comment: Ok I've sent you an email

Comment: fackkk typo again jurjen-folkertsma@hotmail.com ... not that sharp today lol

Comment: I've sent the email again :)